# Parse and plot data received from log-file on-the-fly

Tags: perl, bash, gnuplot, on-the-fly

I want to create a Perl (or Bash) script to create and plot data on-the-fly. That means I want to extract data from a log-file **file.log**, ideally don't write a tmp-file (if it's only possible with a tmp-file, this would be fine too) and plot with Gnuplot. As the logfile is growing, I want to see the additional information in the plot.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17616780/command-and-script-to-re-read-a-file-in-gnuplot) for similar topic.

For Perl, what I have so far is this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $path = "file.log";   
my @grepped;
my $switch = "off";

open(INFILE,"< $path") or die $! \n";
while (my $line = <INFILE>) {

       if ($line =~ m{^Time = (\d+)}){
               push(@grepped,"$1\t");
       };

       if ($line =~ m{^Errors: local = (\d+), global = (\d+)}){
               push(@grepped,"$1\t");
               push(@grepped,"$2\n");
               $switch = "refresh";
       };


if ($switch eq "refresh"){

open(GP, "| gnuplot -persist") or die: $! \n";
print GP << "GNU_EOF";

plot "@grepped" u 2:1
pause 1; refresh; reread;

GNU_EOF

close(GP);
}


}
close(INFILE)};
```

My first problem is that the on-the-fly functionality for Gnuplot isn't working. When the **file.log** gets changed, the refreshing of the Gnuplot-graph isn't working. I don't know if the `-persist` is correct here or if I have to use `replot` option instead of `refresh`. I tried it but it's not working for me.

Second problem is to read the data into array **@grepped** and use it in Gnuplot in one script for a changing input file. One additional restriction is that (as you can see from the code) gnuplot only should refresh the plot if a complete new line in **@grepped** is written. Otherwise errors would occur for sure because of the wrong assignment of data.

When I try a simple script like:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot -persist
plot "data.dat" u 2:1
pause 1; replot; reread;
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot
plot "data.dat" u 2:1
pause 1; refresh; reread;
```

the on-the-fly part works if I change `data.dat` by hand and save it.

Comment: Eh... well, you print the `@grepped` array to gnuplot *before* you add any data to it....? How did you expect that to work?

Comment: You are right of course. This is not really complete code and can't work. I also tried to nest the two `open` but this also isn't working for me.

Comment: The `-persist` is correct, but you must tell `gnuplot` to read from `stdin` with `plot '-' u 2:1`. The input stream must be terminated with an `e`.

Comment: @TLP I changed the code that it makes a bit more sense but I know this can't be working. Therefore I need your help :)

@Christoph How should I define this? `"| gnuplot -persist -e"` Isn't working.

Comment: @bashophil Well, you know that when interpolating an array into a string, the elements are separated by space (or rather, the value contained in `$"`)? So if `@grepped = (1,2,3);`, then `"@grepped"` will be `1 2 3`.

Comment: Sorry, the `e` is required only to terminate inline data (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19344602/2604213). But you must terminate the input stream in some other ways, before you can plot it: `seq 1 5 | gnuplot -e "plot '-'" -persist`. Don't know how to manage this in PERL.

Comment: @TLP Thx. But using `@grepped` instead of `"@grepped"` isn't solving my syntax issues.
@Christoph I think this shouldn't differ in Perl. If you have a part-solution for this Gnuplot-problem (using data on-the-fly) I would be happy about some code or link even if it's a bash script. E.g. piping a file to Gnuplot and change this file manually. Even this isn't working for my script...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two ways for plotting data on-the-fly.

### Looping with gnuplot

You must call `plot` over and over again, the data is preprocessed by an external script. The minimal gnuplot script `filter.gp` is:

```
while (1) {
    plot '< ./myscript.pl' using 2:1
    pause 1
}
```

To stop this, hit `Ctrl+C`.

The Perl script for the preprocessing may look like the following `myscript.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $path = "file.log";   
my @grepped;
my $t = 0;
open(INFILE,"< $path") or die "$! \n";

while (my $line = <INFILE>) {
    if ($line =~ m{^Time = (\d+)}){
        $t = $1;
    };

    if ($line =~ m{^Errors: local = (\d+), global = (\d+)}){
        print "$t\t$1\t$2\n";
    };
};
close(INFILE);
```

Just run it with `gnuplot filter.gp`.

To make it more configurable, one can change the script to use a variable which is passed to gnuplot via the command line:

```
while (1) {
    plot '< ./myscript.pl -f '.path using 2:1
    pause 1
}
```

or use `reread` for this:

```
plot '< ./myscript.pl -f '.path using 2:1
pause 1
reread
```

Call this script with `gnuplot -e "path='file.log';" filtermod.gp`.

That works, but would filters the complete file over and over again.

### Piping from Perl to gnuplot

Here is a Perl script, which basically works for me, but its my first real Perl script, so there may be some nonideal parts. Feel free to comment on that.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $path = "file.log";   
my @grepped;
my $switch = "off";

open(my $gp, "| gnuplot -persist") or die "$! \n";
$gp->autoflush(0);

use File::Tail;
my $file = File::Tail->new(name=>$path, maxinterval=>1, tail=>-1);

while (defined(my $line= $file->read)) {
    if ($line =~ m{^Time = (\d+)}){
        push(@grepped,"$1\t");
    };

    if ($line =~ m{^Errors: local = (\d+), global = (\d+)}){
        push(@grepped,"$1\t");
        push(@grepped,"$2\n");
        $switch = "refresh";
    };

    if ($switch eq "refresh") {
        print $gp <<"GNU_EOF";
plot '-' using 2:1
@grepped
e
GNU_EOF
        $gp->flush;
        $switch = "off"; 
    };
    Time::HiRes::sleep(0.1);
};
```

What I found to be important here is

1. Looping over a changing file.
2. The arrangement of the `autoflush` and `flush`.
3. The `sleep` to allow gnuplot to process the data properly.

That worked for a very small test data file. Don't know if it will for a larger one as well, but should help you a bit further.

Comment: Thx a ton Christoph! Unfortunately I can't test the Perl-only solution yet, but the gnuplot-wrapping-script works great. Especially the gnuplot-intern `while`-loop. I adjusted the script because I want to define the location of the script with the script call. So I use a Bash-script to be able to define variables and pipe a heredoc to gnuplot. Defining the `while`-loop in Bash isn't working, I had to use the `while(1)` in the heredoc (gnuplot).

Comment: @bashophil You can also pass variables to a gnuplot script using the `-e` flag like `gnuplot -e "path='file.log'; sleep=1;" filter.gp` and then use these variables `path` and `sleep` in the script.

Comment: But I also wanted to call the script like `filter.sh path/to/file`. This argument of the path gets transferred to the Perl-script via `plot '< ./myscript.pl -f $pathvar'` e.g. I don't know if this is also possible in gnuplot directly.

Comment: @bashophil Of course. With the command line call of my previous comment, you can change the plot command to `plot '< ./myscript.pl -f '.path`.

Comment: Awesome! This way I am also able to get several log-histories plottet with a single script-call using `set term x11 1`, `set term x11 2` and so on. Thx a lot :)